# Input to the neural network using FFT array

Tags: python, neural-network

Hello everyone so I have 7 folders containing wav files i was able to read all the files and then did a fourier transformation on each one of them so i got 7 fft for each folder
then i inserted the 7 ffts into one list of array
now how can i create the whole neural network and to use the list of array as the input of my neural network ?
here is a small sample of the whole list of array that i have

```
[[[4.20180000e+04 3.40343602e+04 1.81055135e+04 ... 5.40730147e+03
   5.40913603e+03 5.42800000e+03]]

 [[1.70000000e+01 4.19190934e+00 1.55045588e+01 ... 5.62239319e+00
   4.97523412e+00 3.00000000e+00]]

 [[7.70000000e+01 2.34557405e+02 8.23823161e+02 ... 1.60397133e+01
   1.92390084e+01 3.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Asking how to create a whole neural network is quite a large question. Maybe start by googling how to implement simple networks, or how others have implemented NNs on fft data.

Comment: any ideas how can i start with the input of the NN?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by start with the input? If you want to create a neural network that takes fft data as input you'll need to figure out what kind of architecture you want - maybe conv1d or conv2d. Then go from there and see how you need to process your input -- preprocessing, splitting into train and test sets, etc.